# What's the effect of winning the Civil War?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

*The civil war is over. The Imperials won.*

**Will Elisif become the high queen now?**

Everything ended so suddenly, but it's said that they're only waiting for peace. **What now?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, not much of anything it seems. I completed the Civil War quests fairly early in my first play through. I sided with the Imperials and captured Windhelm. Afterward, and I mean waaaaay afterward. 20+ hours later. I still haven't had any follow up quest. All I've noticed is the townspeople in Windhelm call me dog, and miserable wretch... They don't like me. =(